# Oracle 11g Trigger that sets a flag when number below x

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need to create a TRIGGER that sets a flag when a product’s quantity on hand falls below 5.

I've created a table "STP_STOCK" in Oracle 11g and it has the following column:

```
STP_QUANTITY, NUMBER(4,0), RANGE 0-9999
```

How do I create a trigger that sets a flag in SQL?

I've got as far as the following... but have no idea re setting a flag.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER STP_STOCK
AFTER UPDATE
   ON orders
   FOR STP_QUANTITY

BEGIN

END;
```

Comment: Where is that "flag" you want to set?

Comment: Is the "flag" you are trying to set a column in the `STP_STOCK` table?  Or a column in some other table?  Or something else?  You say that you have a table `STP_STOCK`.  But then you try to create a trigger also named `STP_STOCK`.  And you appear to be trying to define the trigger on the `ORDERS` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the flag is in the same table, I would suggest you use a *before* update trigger.  Then you can do something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER STP_STOCK
before UPDATE
   ON orders
   FOR each row    
BEGIN
    if :new.stp_quantity < 5
    then :new.flag := 'Y';
    end if;
END;
```

(I don't have Oracle on hand to test the syntax, so the syntax might have an error.)

You want to do a `before` trigger, so you can just set the value in `:new`.  It is bad practice to update the same table in an `after` trigger.

Presumably, you also want to check if the quantity is larger than 5 and set the flag to `'N'`, but that is not specified in the question.

Finally, instead of a trigger and a flag, you probably really want to do this with a `view` or virtual column.  Something like:

```
select o.*, (case when stp_quantity < 5 then 'Y' else 'N' end) as Flag
from orders o
```

(Note:  I'm using `*` as a convenience.  In practice, you would want to list each column in the view.)